# Extract numbers from string from specific point

Tags: python

Example strings:

`myString1 =  "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png"`

`myString2 =  "/desktop/51232132561/Screenshots/photo_3501.png"`

`myString3 =  "/desktop/12321516123/Screenshots/photo_7501.png"`

`myString4 =  "/desktop/5234324324/Screenshots/photo_11501.png"`

I had a look around, and couldn't really figure out a proper way to do this. I want to be able to also retrieve the last numbers of my strings after the **photo_** part, and store them in another variable (string, not int or float). Furthermore, I don't need the number before **/Screenshots**. It would also be nice if it can work for any number length. The **photo_** will always remain inside the string too.

Comment: [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) might be good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a regex that only matches the end of the string

```
>>> import re
>>> myString1 =  "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png"
>>> re.search(r"photo_(\d+)\.png$", myString1).group(1)
'0000'
```

Comment: Breaks if you have `.PNG` which is still a legit file extension for an image file.

Comment: @dawg - good point. Assuming that this is a unix like operating system, file names are case senstive and extensions are just a convenience - a png could have any name. If OP is concerned about case, then `re.search(r"photo_(\d+)\.png$", myString1, re.IGNORE).group(1)` would catch it.

Comment: *Assuming that this is a unix like operating system, file names are case sensitive and extensions are just a convenience* Well MacOS and iOS are both BSD but the file system is case Insensitive and extension do matter.

Comment: @dawg - didn't realize that. I will remove apple from "unixlike".

Comment: Any unix system cannot use case in a file name on a FAT or HFS partition; ext4 has optional case insensitive files and is case insensitive on Android; it is a bigger issue than just macOS...

Answer (score 2):

This calls for a `regex` solution:

```
import re

mystring = "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png"
your_value = re.findall(r'(photo_[0-9]+)', mystring)[0]

print(your_value) # photo_0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
myString1 =  "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png"
x=re.findall(r'photo_\d+',myString1.split("/")[-1])
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
import re
data = [ 
  "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png", 
  "/desktop/51232132561/Screenshots/photo_3501.png", 
  "/desktop/12321516123/Screenshots/photo_7501.png", 
  "/desktop/5234324324/Screenshots/photo_11501.png"
]

id_regex = re.compile(r".+photo_(\d+)\.png")

ids = [int(id_regex.match(d).groups()[0]) for d in data]
print(ids)  # [0, 3501, 7501, 11501]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it with split function :

```py
myString1 =  "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png"
first_split = myString1.split('photo_')
number = first_split[1].split('.')[0]
print(number)
```

Other way by using regex :

```py
import re
myString1 =  "/desktop/2512754353/Screenshots/photo_0000.png"
number = re.findall(r'\d+', myString1)[1]
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way would be to use `pathlib` in conjunction with `re`.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=photo_)[0-9]*")

pattern.search(Path(myString1).name).group(0)
> '0000'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and split:

```
from pathlib import Path 

fn="/desktop/5234324324/Screenshots/photo_11501.png"
Path(fn).stem.split('_')[-1])

# 11501
```

The pathlib property [.stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) is the name of the path stripped of the path to it and the extension:

```
>>> Path(fn).stem
'photo_11501'
```

Then either split or partition on the `'_'` delimiter:

```
>>> Path(fn).stem.partition('_')
('photo', '_', '11501')
>>> Path(fn).stem.split('_')
['photo', '11501']
```

You can use `split` or `partition` entirely on strings that represent paths:

```
>>> fn.partition('.png')[0].partition('_')[-1]
'11501'
```

But using pathlib allows you to produce those paths as the result of a glob or other method and is likely more robust and certainly more cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using inbuilt string functions would be to slice the string between "photo" and ".png":

```
strings = [myString1, myString2, myString3, myString4]
>>> [s[s.rfind("photo")+6:s.rfind(".png")] for s in strings]
['0000', '3501', '7501', '11501']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```py
import re

myString3 =  "/desktop/12321516123/Screenshots/photo_7501.png"
s = re.findall('\_\d+',myString3)[0]
int(s[1:len(s)])
```

> output: 7501